# PHP Return Array values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Really need some help with the following.

So, my script calls an API on remote server with:

```
    try {
    $api = new ApiClient();
    $api->call('GetNameservers', $postfields);

    return array(
        'success' => true,
        'ns1' => $api->getFromResponse('nameserver1'),
        'ns2' => $api->getFromResponse('nameserver2'),
        'ns3' => $api->getFromResponse('nameserver3'),
        'ns4' => $api->getFromResponse('nameserver4'),
        'ns5' => $api->getFromResponse('nameserver5'),
    );

}
```

The above API call correctly returns what is must:

```
Array
(
[result] => 1000
[resData] => Array
    (
        [domain] => somecooldomain.com
        [status] => Active
        [autorenew] => 0
        [contactid] => 822
        [nameserver1] => ns1.nameserver1.com
        [nameserver2] => ns2.nameserver2.com
        [nameserver3] => ns3.nameserver3.com
        [nameserver4] => ns4.nameserver4.com
        [nameserver5] => 
        [registrationdate] => 2018-06-29
        [expirydate] => 2020-11-03
    )
)
```

My problem comes after:

```
return array(
    'success' => true,
```

This works:

```
'ns1' => $api->getFromResponse('result'),
```

But it is not what I need as the array is nested.  I've tried many things here:

```
'ns1' => $api->getFromResponse('resData.nameserver1'),
'ns1' => $api->getFromResponse(['resData']['nameserver1']),
```

The getFromReponse is as follow:

```
    public function getFromResponse($key)
{
    return isset($this->results[$key]) ? $this->results[$key] : '';
}
```

Comment: have you tried this `$api['resData']['nameserver1']`?

Comment: I tried this, unfortunately, did not work.

Comment: debug: `var_dump($api->getFromResponse('result'), $api->getFromResponse('result')['resData']['nameserver1']);` The first one will show the full structure. The second should return the expected entry from that structure

Comment: Hi Ryan, I just want to confirm the syntax here.  Doing 'ns1' => $api->getFromResponse('result')['resData']['nameserver1'], actually returns  string(4) "1000" string(1) "1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API response returns a multidimensional array, but your function `public function getFromResponse($key)` only has provisions for 1 dimension.

The return value of `$api->getFromResponse('resData')` is actually an array, so it is valid to do something like this: `$api->getFromResponse('resData')['nameserver1']` to get the value of items from the inner array.